# How to update license status when deleting recurring order?

Tags: commerce

Commerce License Billing module has the following function, which automatically deletes corresponding billing cycle if recurring order gets deleted:

```
function commerce_license_billing_commerce_order_delete($order) {
  if ($order->type == 'recurring') {
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $order_wrapper->cl_billing_cycle->delete();
  }
}
```

which is good to keep database clean from zombie billing cycles.

However, the problem is that licenses for the deleted order's products keep the same `Active` status when they were supposed to get `Revoked`. So I tried to write a new function in similar manner:

```
function my_module_entity_delete($entity, $type) {
  if ($type == 'commerce_order') {
    if ($entity->status == 'recurring_open') {
      foreach ($entity->commerce_line_items[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $value) {
        $line_item_id = $value['line_item_id'];
        dpm($line_item_id);
        $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id);
        dpm($line_item);
        if (isset($line_item->cl_billing_license[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'])) {
          $license_id = $line_item->cl_billing_license[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
          $license = entity_load('commerce_license', array($license_id));
          $license[$license_id]->status = '4';
          entity_save('commerce_license', $license[$license_id]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, while the `dpm($line_item_id)` line correctly returns the line item id, the `dpm($line_item)` line always returns empty. Apparently the corresponding line item already gets deleted by that time, so the function is not able to get to its license.

I've found the proposed patch on https://www.drupal.org/project/entity/issues/1789494, but since it's not yet committed, I wonder is there any other way of changing the status of relevant licenses if recurring order is deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it on more granular line-item level:

```
function mymodule_entity_delete($entity, $type) {
  if ($type == 'commerce_line_item') {
    if (isset($entity->cl_billing_license)) { // Means this is recurring order.
      $license_id = $entity->cl_billing_license[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
      $license = entity_load('commerce_license', array($license_id));
      $license[$license_id]->status = '4';
      entity_save('commerce_license', $license[$license_id]);
    }
  }
}
```